# Why do we create instance of Interface instead of it's implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, service, interface, implementation

We often use the Interface & its implementation (service) where we fetch the data & keep the business logics. And from our controller, we just call the necessary methods by using the interface object like-

```
    private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService; // creating interface instance
    public Employee (IEmployeeService employeeService) // constructor
    {
        _employeeService = employeeService;
    }
    public IActionResult GetEmployeeList()
    {
       List<Employee> employees = _employeeService.GetEmployees(); // calling GetEmployees() method via Interface's instance
    }
```

Now, here why can't we create the instance of the Interface implementation like-

```
private readonly EmployeeService _employeeService;
```

Comment: The advantages of coding against an interface rather than a concrete class are well documented in many places. You should do some research and you'll find plenty of existing information. As a start, one of the most important reasons is that it makes testing easier.

Comment: You may also revert the question. Why would you care for the concrete implementation? Why is is not enough that your object has some defined functionality which is by providing its interface? Of course you *could*, but why *should* you?

Comment: For your class it might be okay to bind to an actual class depending on your context. However client-code of your class should not be forced to know anything about this implementation-detail. A client just wants to get the information from your class. How this class gets that kind of information is completely up to your class, but irrelevant to the client-code.